# Showing a tensor product is a coproduct in $\text{CRing} - uniqueness$

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

I can see that with the left and right injections $i,j$, the diagram $ R \rightarrow R \otimes S \leftarrow S$ has a homomorphism $h' : R \otimes S \rightarrow C$ by $r \otimes s \mapsto f(r) + g(s)$ such that for any $f: R \rightarrow C$ and $g : S \rightarrow C$  we have $h' \circ i = f$ and $h' \circ j = g$.

But I'm having trouble showing that $h'$ is unique.  I start with letting $k : R \otimes S \rightarrow C$ such that $k \circ i = f, k \circ j = g$.  But from here I'm having trouble continuing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Standard tensor argument.  All your relations between compositions tell you what $h’$ and $k$ do on basis elements, and they do the same thing.  By universality, you’re done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $h':r\otimes s\mapsto f(r)g(s)$. The insertion maps are $r\mapsto r\otimes1$ and $s\mapsto 1\otimes s$. The $k$ for your $f$ and $g$ must
satisfy $k(r\otimes 1)=f(r)$ and $k(1\otimes s)=g(s)$. As $r\otimes s=(r\otimes 1)(1\otimes s)$ in $R\otimes S$ then
$$k(r\otimes s)=k(r\otimes 1)k(1\otimes s)=f(r)g(s).$$